# Angular Validation not working when dot in model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular validation is working when there is no dot(.) in model in this following code...

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="title">Post Title</label>
      <input ng-model="new_title" class="form-control" name="new_title" type="text" required/>
      <p class="error" ng-show="addForm.new_title.$touched && addForm.new_title.$invalid">This field is required</p>
 </div>
```

But it is not working when I use `ng-model="new.title"` like in the following code...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Post Title</label>
        <input ng-model="new.title" class="form-control" name="new.title" type="text" required/>
        <p class="error" ng-show="addForm.new_title.$touched && addForm.new.title.$invalid">This field is required</p>
</div>
```

Here is what I am using `new` in my controller

```
$scope.submit = function(){
    var request = CRUD.create($scope.new);
    request.success(function(response){
    $scope.flash = response.status;
 });
};
```

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Is `new` defined as `{}` ?

Comment: To be able that to work, new must be defined as a Javascript object with { }. How it's declared in your JS?

Comment: yes.. I use it in my controllers

Comment: show us the controller please

Comment: `new` must be defined in [`controllerAs`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example) syntax to make that working!

Comment: You have `.` in name :P

Comment: You can check my edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not change your name along with your model.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Post Title</label>
        <input ng-model="new.title" class="form-control" name="new_title" type="text" required/>
        <p class="error" ng-show="addForm.new_title.$touched && addForm.new_title.$invalid">This field is required</p>
</div>
```

This is how it should look like.

The validation doesn't check your model. It checks the form model that you bind the scope when using `name` attribute. So when checking for errors, you use the `name` attributes of the form and the inputs. You just need to change your name of the input from `new.title` to `new_title`.

Comment: Also `addForm.new.title.$invalid` should become `addForm.new_title.$invalid`.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for noticing that. Edit has been made

Answer (score 1):

You can't use dot `(.)` in variable name. you should use `_` or `camel-case` to declare variable like:

`new_title` or `newTitle`

if want to use dot `(.)` notation then use like

```
var info = {
   title: "your title"
}
```

then you can use like

```
<input ng-model="info.title" class="form-control" name="info.title" type="text" required/>
```

but you cant use `new` as a variable name. `new` is a reserved keyword